# Wordpress is not displaying CSS file

Tags: css, html

I have a crazy problem happening and it is blowing my mind. I installed Wordpress on my Localhost and began developing. I modified the standard twenty twelve theme and add custom HTML and CSS to the whole site (4 or 5 pages.) The site shows up great on my local machine (Mac OSX - Safari 6.0.5, Firefox 23.0. Chrome 29.0).

I transferred my site to my live host (under GoDaddy) and I migrated the database by dumping it and then importing it. Now I can pull my site up under both my localhost and by going to the live host URL and the site looks exactly like it should. However, when I crosscheck the CSS via sites like (browsershots.org and browserstack) the site look terrible. Its almost like the main style.css file is not being linked properly. These browser check sites shows the site in ruins on all operating systems and all browsers. Still though when I bring the site up on my personal machine it looks just as it should. My client pulled the site up from their machine and it looked in ruins, just as the css checking sites depicted it.

I have cleared my browser cache thinking I may be reloading a cached version of the site (giving me false hope that it looks good) however it still appears just like it should while viewing the remote version through my local machine.

Side note:All elements of the page appear to be loading fine. The menu bar is there. The text and content is there. It's just not styled.

Does anyone have any idea what may be going on?

Comment: not much to go on here, can we see a link?

Comment: Please show us how you registered your custom styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I didn't do a search and replace on the database, so Wordpress was looking for the CSS file in my localhost

Comment: Thank you for telling us how you resolved this. Please accept your answer to close the question.